# Remove key from dictionary in Python returning new dictionary

Tags: python, methods, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
```

I need to remove a key, say **c** and return the dictionary without that key in one function call

```
{'a':1, 'b':2}
```

d.pop('c') will return the key value - 3 - instead of the dictionary.

*I am going to need one function solution if it exists, as this will go into comprehensions*

Comment: `d.pop('c') return d`?

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres, it returns the value of 'c', which is 3 in this case.

Comment: I think that it's not `True` because first you remove the value of `c` and now `d = {'a':1, 'b':2}`and if you `return d` this one will returns `{'a':1, 'b':2}`

Comment: Oh.. I see what you mean. I did not realise that all of your comment was code. I thought you were asking if `d.pop('c')` will return _d_ :) Yes, that would work, but I can't use it. I need to use it inside comprehension.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

How about this:

```
{i:d[i] for i in d if i!='c'}
```

It's called [Dictionary Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) and it's available since Python 2.7.

or if you are using Python older than 2.7:

```
dict((i,d[i]) for i in d if i!='c')
```

Comment: Yep, totally works. I have got it to work with:
`dict(set(d.items()) - {('c', 0)})`
But it's because I knew the value the 'c' will take. Your solution is more.. comprehensive

Comment: Turns out performance on small data sets (what I need to operate on) is around the same.

Comment: `dict((i,d[i]) for i in d if i!='c')` -- Brownie points for you for not creating another intermediate list/tuple :)

Comment: Dict comprehension is available since Python 2.7

Comment: Your answer is technically good, but it would be better if you can explain a bit some details, e.g. how it actually works.

Comment: In case of running into NameErrors ("d is not defined"), it is possible to use `(lambda x=d: {key:x[key] for key in x if key != 'c'})()`.

Comment: I recommend using a variable name of `k` rather than `i` because it is storing a dict key, not an index. Also note that you can iterate over `k, v in f.items()`, allowing you to refer to the value with `v` instead of `d[i]`. In the end: `{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k != 'c'}`

Answer (score 31):

Why not roll your own? This will likely be faster than creating a new one using dictionary comprehensions:

```
def without(d, key):
    new_d = d.copy()
    new_d.pop(key)
    return new_d
```

Comment: Yeah, that is a solution. Unfortunetly I am stuck with native methods and I can't add any of my own. But this totally would work.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how come you can't define your own functions?

Comment: It's an assignment I need to complete using only comprehensions and native functions, so no external modules as well.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 16):

If you need an *expression* that does this (so you can use it in a lambda or comprehension) then you can use this little <strike>hack</strike> trick: create a tuple with the dictionary and the popped element, and then get the original item back out of the tuple:

```
(foo, foo.pop(x))[0]
```

For example:

```
ds = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}]
[(d, d.pop('c'))[0] for d in ds]
assert ds == [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5}]
```

Note that this actually modifies the original dictionary, so despite being a comprehension, it's not purely functional.

Answer (score 8):

When you invoke `pop` the original dictionary is modified in place.

You can return that one from your function.

```
>>> a = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
>>> a.pop('foo')
1
>>> a
{'bar': 2}
```

Comment: Nice trick: an alternative to `[a.pop('foo'),a][1]` . actually this is a construct i'd like to use more generally. it is essentially returning the result of a series of statement

Answer (score 1):

solution from me

```
item = dict({"A": 1, "B": 3, "C": 4})
print(item)
{'A': 1, 'B': 3, 'C': 4}

new_dict = (lambda d: d.pop('C') and d)(item)
print(new_dict)
{'A': 1, 'B': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dict comprehension seems to be more elegant

```py
{k:v for k,v in d.items() if k != 'c'}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work,

```
(lambda dict_,key_:dict_.pop(key_,True) and dict_)({1:1},1)
```

EDIT
this will drop the key if exist in the dictionary and will return the dictionary without the key,value pair

in python there are functions that alter an object in place, and returns a value instead of the altered object, {}.pop function is an example.

we can use a lambda function as in the example, or more generic below
(lambda func:obj:(func(obj) and False) or obj)
to alter this behavior, and get a the expected behavior.

Comment: "Your answer certainly is worth a little explanation. Kindly refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Comments would help create searchable content.
"