# How to filter the **kwargs before passing them to a function?

Tags: python, decorator, keyword-argument

I have a decorator:

```
def decorator(func):
     @wraps(func)
     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
         print('something', **kwargs)

         # kwargs.pop('task_id', None)

         func(*args, **kwargs)
        
         print('something', **kwargs)
    
     return wrapper
```

I need to filter the `kwargs` in such a way that they can be passed to the calling function without the `task_id`, but **not removed**. Since after I will need to fully use `kwargs`. Does anyone know how can this be done?

Comment: Did you try putting the `task_id` information back in after calling the function? Did you try creating a new dictionary with every key except `task_id`, and using that to call the function?

Comment: You can use `{k: v for k,v in kwargs.items() if k not in {'task_id'}}` (using a set to be able to generalize).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `task_id` as a separate keyword argument, so it will be automatically excluded from other `kwargs`:

```
def decorator(func):
     @wraps(func)
     def wrapper(*args, task_id=None, **kwargs):
         func(*args, **kwargs)
    
     return wrapper
```

Answer (score 1):

When inside the function (`wrapper`), `kwargs` is just a dict. So you can [remove a key while returning a new dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665809/remove-key-from-dictionary-in-python-returning-new-dictionary):

```py
def decorator(func):
     @wraps(func)
     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
         print('something', **kwargs)

         func(*args, **{kw: kwargs[kw] for kw in kwargs if kw != "task_id"})
        
         print('something', **kwargs)
    
     return wrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one variant, but it looks so bad. So I did:

```
def decorator(func):
     @wraps(func)
     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

         print('something', **kwargs)
         new_kwargs = kwargs,copy()
         new_kwargs.pop('task_id', None)

         func(*args, **new_kwargs)
        
         print('something', **kwargs)
    
     return wrapper
```

If anyone have better variant, it will be good.